# Check events emited by lightning component from managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, lightning-renderer

I have to cal some action in  my lightning component when the child component finished rendering. Best practice AFAIK is to handle event thrown by child component, but the problem is that I dont have access to child codebase because it is from managed package. I dont know if it throws any custom events, also cant find any info how to catch ootb lightnig render events from child cmp. Pls let me know if You have any Idea to acheive that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the aura documentation in the org where the managed package is installed.  I believe global events and components that you have access to should be available.

From the docs:
The documentation you create will be available at https://YOUR_DOMAIN.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app, where  is the name of your custom Salesforce domain.

Comment: Custom events are added somwhere there?

Comment: I think so. It will depends on what was included by the managed package owner.  If you expand Events -> namespace of the managed package global events should be listed

Answer (score 5):

You can request your managed package application provider to provide a global event for your scenario .

The managed package vendor will need to something similar to below code

```
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
```

Controller code

```
({
     "onRender" : function(cmp) {
        var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:appEvent");
        appEvent.fire();
      }
 })
```

This assumes there is an event definition file and the Event is of type application event and marked global

```
<!--c:appEvent-->
 <aura:event type="APPLICATION" access="GLOBAL">
   <!-- Add aura:attribute tags to define event shape.
 </aura:event>
```